# How to configure runtime property parameters in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Using `IntelliJ`, i set up a property

[image]

I can't, however access it as `System.getProperty("Key")` (I get `null`)

Is this not the way to do it? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more than one way to do this, but this way definitely works:

[image: Setting VM Options]

To get to this dialog you click the dropdown on the top (right below the menu bar) and select `Edit  Configurations...`.  Click `OK` then run the Configuration by pressing the green play button.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a "VM options" value, for example, -DKey="key".

Comment: Could you expand this answer?